# Why is VS Code not working on Ubuntu 21.10 LTS?

Tags: 22.04, visual-studio-code

I've been using ubuntu 21.1LTS all along and VS Code for all my projects but suddenly, it doesn't work anymore. I can see the icon among my apps but when I double click, nothing happens. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 was **not** a LTS, and had no upgrade path to 22.04; as it's intended & only supported upgrade path was to the next release was being Ubuntu 21.10.  Your details highlight user errors (ie. potential pitfalls as you're outside of *supported* upgrade paths), if they weren't typos.

Comment: Please don't make up details and be precise.  The first major release on an *even* year is the *long-term-support* release; ie. in 2022 the April release was the LTS, ie. 22.04 LTS. The format of main releases is *year.month* with 2000 subtracted from the year (Ubuntu didn't exist prior to 2004). Ubuntu 21.10 or the 2021-October release was not a *even* year, nor the first (April) so wasn't a LTS release. Are you using Ubuntu? if so what release as your release details aren't clear (*Ubuntu also didn't have a release in January; ie there is no 2021-January*) release).

Comment: Were you using Ubuntu 21.10?  then *release-upgraded* to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and the issue started after that upgrade?